# Python Interpreter Behavior?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7.

This is what happened:

```
>>> 2+++2
4
```

I am not sure as to how the python interpreter interprets this expression.

The only reason I can come up with is that successive "+" after the first "+" are considered as unary operators and the first "+" is considered as a binary operator, but what is actually the mechanism that is happening I am not sure of.

I would want someone to answer the question in terms of the grammar specifics of Python programming language and also report some other ambiguous expressions. I came up with some other expressions which are listed below (with their results):

```
>>> 2------------2
4
>>> 2+-2+-2+-2+-2+-2-------------------------2
-10
```

Comment: Neither of these are ambiguous (only pointless), nor are you asking a question about a real programming problem you're facing.

Comment: Moreover, asking for more ambiguous expressions makes this question not-constructive.

Answer (score 7):

You're right; Python is interpreting this as `2 + (++2)`, as you might expect. You can see this by looking at the compiled bytecode for 2+2 and 2+++2, as follows:

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda: 2+2)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               2 (4)
              3 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(lambda: 2+++2)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 UNARY_POSITIVE      
              7 UNARY_POSITIVE      
              8 BINARY_ADD          
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

You might want to know why Python parses 2+++2 like this. First, the code gets split up into tokens:

```
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> import tokenize
>>> tokenize.generate_tokens(StringIO("2+++2").readline)
  9 <generator object generate_tokens at 0x0000000007BC7480>
>>> list(tokenize.generate_tokens(StringIO("2+++2").readline))
  10 
[(2, '2', (1, 0), (1, 1), '2+++2'),
 (51, '+', (1, 1), (1, 2), '2+++2'),
 (51, '+', (1, 2), (1, 3), '2+++2'),
 (51, '+', (1, 3), (1, 4), '2+++2'),
 (2, '2', (1, 4), (1, 5), '2+++2'),
 (0, '', (2, 0), (2, 0), '')]
```

It's the parser that then associates the list of tokens into a syntax tree:

```
>>> st = ast.parse("2+++2")
>>> st
  36 <_ast.Module at 0x7d2acc0>
>>> ast.dump(st)
  37 'Module(body=[Expr(value=BinOp(left=Num(n=2), op=Add(), right=UnaryOp(op=UAdd(), operand=UnaryOp(op=UAdd(), operand=Num(n=2)))))])'
```

This follows standard disambiguation rules.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the way Python defines [unary](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations) and [binary](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations) arithmetic operations. Especially unary expressions:

```
u_expr ::=  power | "-" u_expr | "+" u_expr | "~" u_expr
```

You can see the part `"+" u_expr`, which pretty much means that a number of `+` followed by a number is a valid unary expression (sort of recursive, huh?).

On the other hand you got these two:

```
m_expr ::=  u_expr | m_expr "*" u_expr | m_expr "//" u_expr | m_expr "/" u_expr
        | m_expr "%" u_expr
a_expr ::=  m_expr | a_expr "+" m_expr | a_expr "-" m_expr
```

Which pretty much mean, when you have a binary expression, your read the first atom, then the sign, and read the next binary/unary expression. Which read code like:

```
2+-2+-2+-2+-2+---2+-2
```

essentially like:

```
2 + (-2) + (-2) + (-2) + (-2) + (-(-(-2))) + (-2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly plain in the [grammar](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html):

```
arith_expr: term (('+'|'-') term)*
term: factor (('*'|'/'|'%'|'//') factor)*
factor: ('+'|'-'|'~') factor | power
```

So since any factor may be preceded by one of the unary operators, this will extend until the arithmetic expression consumes the binary operator. It's not ambiguous at all, since we have neither C's ++ operator nor Haskell's ability to define new ones.